# Android iapV3: consuming an ond item

Tags: android, exception

I am trying to implement both consumable & non consumable items.
My problem : I would like to consume an item bought sometime ago (as I purchased and didn't consume it immediately (what an error...)).

I've tried calling the `consumeItem();` method when receiving "already bought" message in my purchase handler, but every time I call this method on this product (works for the new ones), I get a NullPointerException.

Here are my methods :

```
public void consumeItem() {

        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);

    }

    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                Inventory inventory) {

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // Handle failure
            } else {

                mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU),
                        mConsumeFinishedListener);

            }
        }
    };

    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
        public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {

            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // clickButton.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                // handle error
            }

        }
    };
```

Any help would be welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can only consume an item when the puchase is made.
Well, to solve the problem, I implemented the concerned product consumption, and canceled my test order on my merchant account. All worked fine when Google cache updated.